# Can the last い in かわいい be dropped?

Tags: pronunciation, contractions, i-adjectives, vowels, long-vowels

In the Genki I textbook, it says that the i and the u vowels are sometimes dropped when placed between voiceless consonants or at the end of an utterance preceded by voiceless consonants.

The example given, すきです, demonstrates both points.

Currently, I am learning about adjectives and was wondering whether the vowel drop is also applied to adjectives (or words in general) that end in "いい", for example かわいい and うれしい.

Since the i is at the end of an utterance preceded by voiceless consonants in both examples, I believe that the vowel drop is acceptable. Therefore, is it appropriate in speech to say "kawaides" and "ureshides" or do I have to say the long i-vowel?

Comment: Why do you think the last i of かわいい is "preceded by voiceless consonant"?

Comment: @broccoliforest The book said "preceded by voiceless consonants," not "a" voiceless consonant. Because of this, I assumed that dropping may be necessary as long as there is a voiceless consonant in the word before the vowel.

Comment: @AppleMango I think it should have said `(directly) preceded by a voiceless consonant` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vowel drop described in your textbook happens between consonants. However, even though the vowel is dropped, the rhythm of the word isn't changed.

> [[s.ki.de.s]] ↔ [[su.ki.de.su]]

(the dot `.` denotes separation of syllables).

You cannot do the same with the [[i]] in かわいいです [[ka.wa.i.i.de.s(u)]] or うれしいです. (I don't understand your comment about voiceless consonants, but neither [[i]] is between consonants.)

---

However, a final -i is sometimes dropped in colloquial speech. I would describe this as a separate phenomenon, though.

> 痛い → 痛っ or 痛ッ
>   寒い → 寒っ or 寒ッ

In writing (e.g. ads, manga), the silent mora is usually represented by っ (or ッ).

For your two words, you'd get

> カワイい → カワいっ
>   うれしい → うれしっ

The second be pronounced [[u.ɺe.ɕ. ]], i.e. with a(n almost?) silent final -i. However, note that the rhythm is not <s>[[u.ɺeɕ]]</s>.

Comment: かわいい → かわっ won't happen since you can't cut back the verb stem (you'll get かわいっ).

Comment: @broccoliforest Not even かわいい → かわいっ → かわい → かわっ? (How else would you get something like くそ**かわ**?)

Comment: ○○かわ is just a 2-2 mora abbreviation template like あけおめ. It isn't grammatical itself as you can say キモかわ or [ポンかわ](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/t/a/%E3%83%9D%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B3%E3%83%84%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8F%E3%81%84%E3%81%84) too.

Comment: @broccoliforest I see, I edited that part out, then.

Answer (score 2):

The vowels aren't "dropped"; they simply become voiceless, which is explained (poorly) to English speakers as being "dropped" because the concept of voiceless vowels doesn't exist in English. In these two examples, the い is voiced in both cases.

For かわいい, the voicing of わ means that the first い is voiced, and thus the adjacent final い must also be voiced. Aside from that, though, if it's followed by です then it doesn't matter since the [d] at the start is always voiced. Thus the final い in うれしい must also be voiced. But since vowels are voiced by default, the final い would also make the previous い voiced.

Comment: Well, sometimes they're entirely missing rather than being voiceless.

Comment: @snailplane Yes, but that's an entirely separate phenomenon than devoicing.